# Download File in JS

Tags: javascript, file, download, aura-framework

i'm trying to download an `xlsx` file in `aura` component controller. This is my code, but it's not working:

```
var data = response.getReturnValue();
var blob = new Blob([data], { type : 'text/plain' });

console.log("jsonBlob", blob);

var link = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.location = link;
```

Comment: What error are you getting? You may need to add an `await` before response, since the call is async

Comment: no error nothing happens